# How to escape special characters in ansible shell module

Tags: bash, ansible, yaml

I tried bash escape and double quotes methods to escape the special characters in below shell command, But both didn't work, What is the proper way to escape special characters in ansible playbook?

```
 The offending line appears to be:

                 name: Syncing system date with htpdate failed!, Trying wget method...
                 shell: date -s "$(curl -s --head http://google.com | grep '^Date:' | sed 's/Date: //g' ) +0530"
                                                                                                ^ here

    exception type: <class 'yaml.scanner.ScannerError'>
    exception: mapping values are not allowed in this context
      in "<unicode string>", line 15, column 93
```

Comment: I think you mean `shell: date -s "$(curl -s --head http://google.com | grep '^Date:' | sed 's/Date: //g') +0530"` where `s/Date/: //g` should be `s/Date: //g`.

Comment: And of course `grep x | sed 's/y/z/'` is better written `sed -n '/x/s/y/z/p'`.  See also [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) and the `/g` flag is also useless unless you specifically expect there to be multiple occurrences of `Date: ` on the line.

Comment: @tripleee The problem is the colon followed by a space `: ` in the value. I just wanted to write an answer, but now it's closed! There's no problem with the dollar sign.

Comment: How can one flag duplicates as wrong?

Comment: You can flag for mod attention, but no need for that now; I'll reopen for now. The colon as such is fine but the extra slash before it is obviously a typo. You could argue that this should instead be closed as trivial typo and that it's unlikely to help future visitors, but I was hesitant to close in the first place so let's just leave it for someone who is better familiar with Ansible to make the final call.

Comment: For reference, the duplicate was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717778/ansible-regex-escape-dollar-character

Comment: that extra slash is a typo, I have corrected it now, also added complete error message, @tinita Awaiting you answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the problems here is the colon followed by a space `:`. This is usually an indicator for a mapping key.

YAML does not allow nested mappings on one line, e.g.:

```
foo: bar: baz
```

That's why YAML designers chose to forbid `:` in a mapping value if it's on the same line as the key. (It could have been been solved as well by simply ignoring further occurances and treat that as regular content.)

You have several choices. You can just put the whole value in quotes, which is not a good idea in this case since you have both single and double quotes which you would have to escape then.

A workaround can be to escape the space in the sed command:

```
shell: date -s "$(curl -s --head http://google.com | grep '^Date:' | sed 's/Date:\ //g') +0530"
```

A more general solution is to use a folded block scalar:

```
shell: >
  date -s "$(curl -s --head http://google.com | grep '^Date:' | sed 's/Date: //g') +0530"
```

You could even seperate this into several lines now, because the folded block scalar will fold consecutive lines into one:

```
shell: >
  date -s "$(curl -s --head http://google.com
  | grep '^Date:' | sed 's/Date: //g') +0530"
```

The second problem is, as Javier mentioned, the sed expression `s/Date/: //g`. You probably want `s/Date: //g`. Also look at the suggestion by @tripleee how to improve your command.

Comment: Thank you so much,  folded block scalar solution fixed my issue

Comment: Thanks, my issue is fixed with folded block

Answer (score -1):

Consider that escape caracter is `\` not `/`

**EDIT**

Your problem is not related to escape character, it is caused your `sed` expression has an additional `/`

`sed 's/Date: ///g'`

Should be writen like
`sed 's/foo/bar/g'`

In your case `sed 's/Date: //g'`

Comment: I think that your reply should be a comment. It does not propose an answer to the question. Besides, I don't see anything that needs escaping. He has used double quotes for the bigger quote, then single quotes inside that.

Comment: I'm guessing the answerer is unfamiliar with `sed` and imagined that the slash delimiters in `sed 's/foo/bar/'` were supposed to be backslashes.

Comment: @alvaro-nino that extra slash was a typo, corrected it now