# Escaping double quotes and braces inside Ansible variable

Tags: ansible, yaml, escaping

I'm trying to use Ansible's command module to run the following command:-

```
aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket ovc-ov90test --server-side-encryption-configuration '{"Rules": [{"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {"SSEAlgorithm": "AES256"}}]}'
```

Naturally, I want to pass in the flag values through playbook variables, and this is what I am using:

```
---
- name: Create s3 bucket
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    bucket_name: ovc-ov90test
    encryption_rules: '{\"Rules\"\: [{\"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault\"\: {\"SSEAlgorithm\"\: \"AES256\"}}]}'
  tasks:
    - name: Launch 
      block:
        - name: Encrypt the bucket
          command: 'aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket {{ bucket_name }} --server-side-encryption-configuration {{ encryption_rules }}'
```

And this is my error:

```
TASK [Encrypt the bucket] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["aws", "s3api", "put-bucket-encryption", "--bucket", "ovc-ov90test", "--server-side-encryption-configuration", "{\"Rules\":", "[{\"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault\":", "{\"SSEAlgorithm\":", "\"AES256\"}}]}"], "delta": "0:00:00.648339", "end": "2021-02-11 11:56:49.423938", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 252, "start": "2021-02-11 11:56:48.775599", "stderr": "\nusage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]\nTo see help text, you can run:\n\n  aws help\n  aws <command> help\n  aws <command> <subcommand> help\n\nUnknown options: {\"SSEAlgorithm\":, \"AES256\"}}]}, [{\"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault\":", "stderr_lines": ["", "usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]", "To see help text, you can run:", "", "  aws help", "  aws <command> help", "  aws <command> <subcommand> help", "", "Unknown options: {\"SSEAlgorithm\":, \"AES256\"}}]}, [{\"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault\":"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I've also tried the following values for `encryption_values`(i. escaping double quotes AND both curly and square braces, and ii. escaping only double quotes and curly braces), but none work:

```
encryption_rules: '\{\"Rules\"\: \[\{\"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault\"\: \{\"SSEAlgorithm\"\: \"AES256\"\}\}\]\}'
encryption_rules: '{\"Rules\"\: \[{\"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault\"\: \{\"SSEAlgorithm\"\: \"AES256\"}}\]}'
```

Using `{{ encryption_rules | quote }}` inside the task after removing the single quotes from the `encryption_rules` variable doesn't work either. I'm guessing the solution is some combination of escaping the right characters but I can't figure out which. Any help would be appreciated!

PS: This runs correctly on the command line so IAM permissions are definitely not the problem.

Comment: I have debugged your issue, the issue is when passing the json to the command module, it is splitting it by space which results into an incorrect command and `aws` utility generates the error. I have tried to wrap up the JSON as a single value but ansible either replaces all the double quotes to single quotes or removes them completely due to which the `aws`  utility complains. Its the place to look for if you are searching for the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The key problem was (like @tinita pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787560/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-ansible-shell-module)) the colon followed by a space `:` . I also ended up using the folded scalar in the command parameter to save myself the headache of unbalanced quotes. This works-

```
---
- name: Create s3 bucket
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    bucket_name: ovc-ov90test
    encryption_rules: '{\"Rules\":\ [{\"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault\":\ {\"SSEAlgorithm\":\ \"AES256\"}}]}'
  tasks:
    - name: Launch 
      block:
        - name: Encrypt the bucket
          command: >
            aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket ovc-ov90test --server-side-encryption-configuration {{ encryption_rules }}
```

Comment: I tried with the folded scalar but didn't escaped the quotes in the `encyption_rules`. I think I missed to do that. Good find.